# How to accelerate the code which convert tensor to numpy array in tensorflow_datasets?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensor, tensorflow-datasets

Although I want to convert tensor to numpy array in tensorflow_datasets, my code is progressively drastically slow down.
Now, I use the lsun/bedroom dataset which has over 3 million images.
How to accelerate my code?

My code saves tuple which has numpy array every 100,000 images.

```
train_tf = tfds.load("lsun/bedroom", data_dir="{$my_directory}", download=False)
train_tf = train_tf["train"]
for data in train_tf:
    if d_cnt==0 and d_cnt%100001==0:
        train = (tfds.as_numpy(data["image"]), )
    else:
        train += (tfds.as_numpy(data["image"]), )

    if d_cnt%100000==0 and d_cnt!=0:
        with open("{$my_directory}/lsun.pickle%d"%(d_cnt), "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(train, f)

    d_cnt += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` condition is never going to get executed after the first pass and consequently your `train` variable keeps accumulating.

I think you wish to have condition as:

```
if d_cnt!=0 and d_cnt%100001==0:
    train = (tfds.as_numpy(data["image"]), )
```

Comment: Thank you for teaching me!! I made a easy mistake. After I revise the code, the code is drastically speed up!

Comment: No problem. :) Happy coding